# Attempted Installation of Ubunutu Server

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation, windows, lvm

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS on a Windows HP desktop (one of those that come already built and packed with Windows). I'm installing Ubuntu from a disk and in the Filesystem Setup screen I chose to partition the entire disk and set up LVM (That was one of the options that had on the screen). It started installing it but it failed after a minute or so.

When the error occurred, these were the steps leading up to it. This was displayed when the error occurred.

```
curtin command install
 preparing for installation
  configuring storage
   running 'curtin block-meta simple'
    removing previous storage devices
    configuring disk: disk-sda
    configuring disk: disk-sdb
```

The full log is in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heVMY.jpg). Here are some of the last lines

```
     OSError: [Errno failed to find device at path %s] /dev/sdb
     [Errno failed to find device at path %s] /dev/sdb
Stderr:''
```

Comment: I see /dev/sdb is card reader and you try to install something to it?

Comment: @AlvinLiang Unless the default options of Ubuntu Server installation is to do that, then no.

Comment: So I restarted the computer when it failed and now I am able to successfully install it. The question isn't technically answered and if someone would be able to understand the cause to the problem that would be helpful. So I'll leave it open for now.

Comment: Did the installer create a crash file on /var/crash on the install media? (perhaps not, if it was a read-only media). Without the .crash file, there is insufficient information to answer the question. Might have been a loose cable, power surge, software bug, gremlin, cosmic ray, etc. So many possibilities.